# Error with transrate.hld function from relsurv package in R: "Currently only TypeLT 1 is implemented"

Tags: survival-analysis

I'm currently working on an epidemiological project in R and I have to use the relsurv package to transform a rate table with the transrate.hld function. As I understand, this function is supposed to handle rate tables from different sources and formats. However, I've encountered a persistent issue.

When I attempt to run the function using the "PER.csv" file as input, I receive the following error message:

```
Error in transrate.hld("PER.csv"): 
  Currently only TypeLT 1 is implemented
```

The confusing part is that there isn't an apparent typeLT argument for the function, so I'm unsure how to proceed. The documentation doesn't seem to provide clarity on this specific issue, and I'm wondering if there's something unique about the format or structure of the CSV file I'm using.

For reference, the "PER.csv" file I am working with was sourced from the website LifeTable. The specific download link for the file is here.

Is anyone familiar with this problem or have any insights on potential solutions or workarounds? I'd greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions.

Comment: Update: 
The specific download web for the file is here:
https://www.lifetable.de/Country/Country?cntr=PER